# NSOutlineView doesn't display the blue guide/separator when dragging-in

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview

I have implemented the drag & drop feature for an `NSOutlineView`. I can drag-in new items into it and also reorder the items. However, there's a **strange behaviour**:

**If one or more items have been reordered** (by dragging & dropping), when a new item is dragged in, the `NSOutlineView` **doesn't show the usual "blue separator line" between two rows** (where it may accept the drop). Instead, **a gap is opened** with the same animation as that of a local reordering.

If no item has been reordered, the blue line shows as usual.

The `NSOutlineView` is populated solely with an `NSOutlineViewDataSource`. It's just been migrated from a "cocoa binding"(with `NSTreeController`) set-up which worked without this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This [NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle) controls the separation behaviour.

I accidentally commented out the line `outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = .sourceList`

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
                 draggingSession session: NSDraggingSession,
                 willBeginAt screenPoint: NSPoint,
                 forItems draggedItems: [Any])
{
    outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = .gap
}

func outlineView(
        _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        draggingSession session: NSDraggingSession,
        endedAt screenPoint: NSPoint,
        operation: NSDragOperation)
    {
        outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = .sourceList
    }
```